# TCL -- Setting variable value from regular expression

Tags: tcl

Parsing a blob of text using TCLs regexp and trying to assign the match to a variable. I understand the match is stored in match, but I am restricted to encompassing the statements within 'set found'.

This does not work:

```
set text "asdf asdf bob foobar 123456@bar dksl: dpee" # simulating blob of text

set found [set blob $text]; regexp -nocase {\d{6}(?:@bar)} $blob match; return $found;

puts $found
```

Any assistance in how to go about it?

Comment: What are you wanting `$found` to be?

Answer (score 0):

Your script has several issues, but the regex is mostly fine. The following will work as expected:

```
regexp -nocase {(\d{6})(?:@bar)} $text _ found
```

(Mind the grouping parentheses!)

Problems with your script:

- Don't use `return` (there is no need, because you are not returning from a `proc`). As a consequence, the line `puts $found` ends up as dead code.
- Why all the fuzz with re-assigning to `blob` etc.